# Is there a ClaimTypes property to represent "city"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity

I've been looking at the various `System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimTypes` properties ([Class reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.claims.claimtypes.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)) to see if there is a pre-defined type for each of my user model attributes.  It appears that there is with the except of city.  For example, I see each of the address fields I would need except for city:

- `ClaimTypes.StreetAddress`
- `ClaimTypes.StateOrProvince`
- `ClaimTypes.PostalCode`

I did notice that there is a `ClaimTypes.Locality`; should this be used to represent city?  (It doesn't sound like that is its purpose).  Or is there some other ClaimTypes property to represent city that I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, your supposition was right. According to the [Claim Catalog](http://wiki.informationcard.net/index.php?title=Claim_Catalog):

> (l in RFC 2256) Locality component of a subject?s address information. According to
> [RFC 2256](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2256): “This attribute
> contains the name of a locality, such as a city, county or other
> geographic region.” e.g. Redmond.

[RFC 2256](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2256) says:

> 5.8. l
>
> This attribute contains the name of a locality, such as a city,
> county or other geographic region (localityName).
>
> ```
> ( 2.5.4.7 NAME 'l' SUP name )
> ```

More official details from Microsoft you can find in [PDF](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/1/a/11ac6505-e4c0-4e05-987c-6f1d31855cd2/Identity_Selector_Interoperability_Profile_V1.5.pdf) format, available for downloading here: [Identity Selector Interoperability Profile specification and companion guides](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18221).